# Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled | Using react + webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, webpack-dev-server, babel-loader

I was codding and my program was working very well, but I dont know why now is giving this error, but yesterday wasn't, and I already had this "DropzoneComponent"

Here is where is te error:

```
const pushIcon = (i) => {
> 129 |       return <Icon filetype={config.iconFiletypes[i]} key={'icon-component' + i} />
      |              ^
  130 |     }
  131 |
  132 |     if (config.showFiletypeIcon && config.iconFiletypes && (!files || files.length < 1)) {
```

This is what errors means:

> Syntax Error: SyntaxError: /home/proit/Documentos/Projetos/ServiceDesk/Frontend/src/components/ReactDropzoneComponent/src/react-dropzone.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled (129:14):

> Add @babel/preset-react (https://git.io/JfeDR) to the 'presets' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
> If you want to leave it as-is, add @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx (https://git.io/vb4yA) to the 'plugins' section to enable parsing.

I had already try to add babel preset react to my .babelrc

My .babelrc:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx",
        "react-hot-loader/babel",
        [
            "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
            {
                "loose": true
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that you have some uncompiled components in your node_modules?

Comment: Also, we probably need to see your webpack config

Comment: Okay... [this](https://pastebin.com/dWdifyGX) is my webpack.config,js

Comment: And... maybe i has some uncompiled... i'll check

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with config. Try to remove `exclude: /node_modules/` from babel loader. If it will work, you will have build node_modules, or remove uncompiled dependency

Comment: Sorry about the late, i've deleted the node_modules as you say and it works!